# "Equal situation", which sentence is correct?

Tags: grammar

> He and she have equal situation.
>
> They are in equal situations.
>
> They are in equal situation.

Comment: A sentence is "true" if it is not a lie. We don't know if your sentences are true, because we do not know "him" or "her" or their situation. I assume you want to know which sentence, if any) is _correct_, _grammatical_ or _idiomatic_.

Comment: I'd avoid them all.

Answer (score 1):

> *He and she have equal situation.

For starters, we need an article (*an equal situation*).

If someone *has* a situation, they have a problem. I doubt that is the meaning you are aiming for.

> *They are in equal situation.

Again, we need an article. This sentence would indicate that "they" are in a similar situation as someone else that we mentioned earlier, or that his situation is similar to hers.

> They are in equal situations.

Here, you have the right article (plural indefinite article is the *zero* article). In this case, *his* situation is similar to *her* situation.

Now, all three sentences sound off to me, because I would not use *equal* to describe situations.

_Situations may be *similar*, or even *identical*, but *equal* gives a different feeling. In mathematics, two things are *equal* is the have the same *value*. In English, things are equal if they have the same value, importance or rights. The two things do not have to be the same:

> Man and woman are equal. -> *this does not mean they are the same!*

If the situation that *he* is in is the same as the situation that *she* is in, the most idiomatic way to say that is

> They are in the same situation.

Note that I also switched to a definite article: *the* situation is defined as the one that they are both in.